# Send message to a running python websocket client

Tags: python, websocket

I'm currently using the websocket-client library to connect to a websocket by following the example code:

```py
def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send('{ "event": "subscribe", "channel": "sensor"+i }')
        time.sleep(1)
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)

ws.on_open = on_open
ws.run_forever()
```

however if I try to send additional message to the websocket on-demand (say subscribe additional channels,

```py
ws.send('{ "event": "subscribe", "channel": "sensor5" }')
```

How would I be able to achieve such? As the ws.run_forever() is already running, how can I get hold of the running websocket instance to submit the message?

Comment: You could execute `run_forever()` on a different thread. Your main thread can then do additional `send()`s. Though I don't see how that would help since you close your websocket after about 4 seconds anyway

Comment: ooo thanks for pointing that out, if I take out the close(), can you let me know how I manage between the main and background thread?

Comment: If this is your entire program (except for the `on_*` functions) you do a `thread.start_new_thread` for `ws.run_forever` and some form of custom infinite loop where you add the options to listen to more events. You could for example read stdin and send each line as-is to the socket.

Answer (score -1):

It's more of a listener than the sender, for sending you can use [this](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client#short-lived-one-off-send-receive):

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("ws://echo.websocket.org/")
print("Sending 'Hello, World'...")
ws.send("Hello, World")
```

For Listener in your question snippet, you had `on_message`

Of whose implementation you can do:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message) #do  something with the message
```

Comment: but how do I continue to listen to new messages from existing websocket connection?

Comment: when establishing a connection you need to specify on_message, on_error, on_close these func will be called correspondingly with parameters

Comment: @harshil9968 It sounds like you should re-read the OPs question. As far as I can see, you are not giving and answer to the actual question.